# Resize a rebuild CPQ hardware RAID

Tags: linux, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have a HP/Compaq DL360 with two 73gig HDs and a Smart Array 6i in a mirror, and CentOS 5.5.I'm low on space, so I alternately swapped in two 300 gig units and let the RAID card rebuild them. Now I have two 300's that the HP Linux CLI utility sees, but I can't resize the partitions with a Gparted Live CD. I tried to add new partitions with fdisk, but it does not see any of the new free disk space. Do I have to add the space in the RAID BIOS setup?

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend the logical drive within the Array Configuration Utility. In the `hpacucli` utility, you run `ctrl all show config detail`, take note of the unused space. See this example where I have 432GB of raw space, but only a portion of it allocated to logical drives:

```
Smart Array P410i in Slot 0 (Embedded)    (sn: 5001438006FD9A50)

   array A (SAS, Unused Space: 265022 MB)


      logicaldrive 1 (72.0 GB, RAID 1+0, OK)
      logicaldrive 2 (72.0 GB, RAID 1+0, OK)

      physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:3 (port 1I:box 1:bay 3, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:1:4 (port 1I:box 1:bay 4, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
```

Do you have the graphical `cpqacuxe` utility installed? You can do this via the graphical interface as well... But either way, the point is to expand the logical drive to the new array size (reflected by the new 300GB disks). From there, you'll have to reboot. At that point, the usual partition utilities (fdisk, parted, etc.) will see the space.

Also check this link for another example: http://www.flagword.net/2010/12/expanding-sb40c-with-hpacucli/

Or the [Configuring Arrays on HP Smart Array Controllers Reference Guide](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c02289065/c02289065.pdf).